# while installing apex extension for pytorch(python environment) the following error is showing, am unable to solve this problem

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, apex

I want to install apex extension for my pytorch environment, **my system is windows 10 and am using python version 3.8.1 and pip version is 20.0.2**

I read the instructions from this https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex and I executed the command

`pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext`

This error is showing.

> c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py:244: UserWarning: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option.
>         cmdoptions.check_install_build_global(options)
>       Non-user install because site-packages writeable
>       Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-ehoqwpvf
>       Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-uowlsjqi
>       Initialized build tracking at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-uowlsjqi
>       Created build tracker: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-uowlsjqi
>       Entered build tracker: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-uowlsjqi
>       Created temporary directory: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rivnsaa9
>       Cleaning up...
>       Removed build tracker: 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-tracker-uowlsjqi'
>       ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
>       Exception information:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
>           status = self.run(options, args)

Please solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext
> ```

The line specified in your link is

```
$ pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" ./
```

Note that you're missing the final `./`, which is why pip tells you that

> You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")

you're telling it to install, but you're not telling it *what* to install.